# Add nested list elements to nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to add the nested list elements to a dictionary. My current approach only adds the last list element to the dictionary. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
list = [['710.09', '65.09', '2.0'], ['710.09', '65.09', '3.0']]
categories =  {'rent': None, 'size': None, 'rooms': None}

for element in list:
   list=dict(zip(categories, element))
```

```
output: {'rent': 710.09, 'size': 65.09, 'rooms': 3.0}

desired output: {1:{'rent': 710.09, 'size': 65.09, 'rooms': 2.0},2:{'rent': 710.09, 'size': 65.09, 'rooms': 3.0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
list = [['710.09', '65.09', '2.0'], ['710.09', '65.09', '3.0']]
categories = {'rent': None, 'size': None, 'rooms': None}
d = {index + 1: dict(zip(categories, item)) for index, item in enumerate(list)}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'rent': '710.09', 'size': '65.09', 'rooms': '2.0'}, 2: {'rent': '710.09', 'size': '65.09', 'rooms': '3.0'}}
```

Or a little less golfy:

```py
list = [['710.09', '65.09', '2.0'], ['710.09', '65.09', '3.0']]
categories = {'rent': None, 'size': None, 'rooms': None}
totals = dict()
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    totals.update({
        index + 1: dict(zip(categories, item))
    })

print(totals)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [['710.09', '65.09', '2.0'], ['710.09', '65.09', '3.0']]
y = ['rent', 'size', 'rooms']

{i: dict(zip(y, list(
            map(float,j)
            )
        )) for i, j in enumerate(x, 1)}
```

**zip**: It will create a list dict between your keys 'rent', 'size' etc with values given in x

**map**: It will convert the values of x inside list to floats,
finally

**enumerate**: will start the final dictionary with keys start from 1

Combining all of this inside dictionary comprehension to make a final dictionary.

**Output**:

```
{1: {'rent': 710.09, 'size': 65.09, 'rooms': 2.0},
 2: {'rent': 710.09, 'size': 65.09, 'rooms': 3.0}}
```